# How can i show info of user when he logged in into website onto next page for asp.net in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i want to access the the data of user who logged into the website onto next page as he logged in. i am not use the asp.net website tool for that.
please help me to find solution of my problem.....

Comment: Please can you clarify what data about the user you are trying to access about the user, and which login provider/system you are using if you are not using the ASP.NET membership provider. In current form this question is far too vague to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to use is a Session variable, this is the easiest way to use data across pages with one variable.
It might look as follows:

```
Session("pstrLogin") = txtUername.text
```

to access it on another page.

```
strName = Session("pstrLogin").ToString()
```

Hope this is what you wanted.